# Past GRE Question

Tags: combinatorics

Below is a problem from a past math subject GRE exam (GR9367). Is there a quick way to solve this?

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of a set $M$ and let $S_0=\{A,B\}$. For $i\geq 0$, define $S_{i+1}$ inductively to be the collection of subsets $X$ of $M$ that are of the form $C\cup D, C\cap D,$ or $M-C$ (the complement of $C$ in $M$), where $C,D \in S_i$. Let $S=\cup^\infty_{i=0} S_i$. What is the largest possible number of elements of S?

The Answer is $16$.

Am I correct in thinking that there can only be at most  $4$ distinct subsets (the case in which $A$ and $B$ are disjoint proper nonempty subsets), in which case $S$ is the power set on 4 subsets making $|S|=2^4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ is paritioned into the four disjoint sets $X_1=A\cap B$, $X_2=A\setminus B$, $X_3=B\cap A$, $X_4=M\setminus(A\cup B)$. It follows by induction that for any set $C\in S_n$ (and hence also in $S$), either $X_i\subseteq C$ or $X_i\cap C=\emptyset$. Since any set in $S$ is hence characterized by these four choices, there are only $2^4$ possible subsets. To attain the bound $16$, start with $A,B$ such that none of the $X_i$ is empty: You can obtain the $X_i$ in a few steps and then all combinations as unions of the $X_i$.

Answer (score 1):

In the maximal case, you have $A, B$ have nonempty intersecion and their union have nonempty complement. Then I think the union of any subset of $\{A-B, B-A, A\cap B, X-(A\cup B)\}$ is possible, so that gives the desired $2^4=16$ subsets. (These are the $4$ regions a Venn Diagram of these sets would be divided into, and you can get any subset of these four regions.)